# Click button on website then scrape web page

Tags: python, onclick, click, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I have a website I would like to click a button on then scrape the website using python the html code between the button is:

```
 <span id="exchange-testing" class="exchange-input nav-link" data track="&amp;lid=testing&amp;lpos=site_settings" data-value="testing">Testing</span>
```

Is this possible? I am able to scrape all the data I need from the page but I need to click the button first.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 26):

Basically, you have two options:

- *high-level approach*: automate a real browser using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) or, in other words, make the browser repeat all the user actions needed to get to the page with the desired data.
- *low-level approach*: when you click the button, investigate what is happening under the hood - explore the "Network" tab of browser developer tools and see what requests are being made. Then, simulate them in your scraper. Here, you may consider using tools like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for making requests, handling scraping sessions, submitting forms etc and tools like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) for html parsing. Also, [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) web-scraping framework is a must see.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a button you want to click then scrape then do the following:

1. Inspect the button element . the link the button will open after clicking it will always be in the html you opened .
2. Scrape this link and do requests.get(link) . this becomes equivalent to clicking button .

but this isn't applicable when the button needs to activate some js function that should've run on clicking the element.