# Interact with web pages using python

Tags: python

I am quite fluent in Python, but have only really used it for data analysis.

I would like to learn how I can interact with webpages. For instance, I want to start by writing a code that will press a button on a webpage for me.

I just don't know where to start or what to google to find resources about this.

Could anyone point me out in the right directions, or suggest some key words that I could search for?

Thanks.

Comment: I use Selenium. Don't know if there's a general name for that sort of thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823600/click-button-on-website-then-scrape-web-page    This might get you started....

Comment: Thanks guys. Got down votes as expected, but I literally don't know how to "say what you tried" or "provide error" messages with a question like this.

Comment: You may be interested in https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize.

Comment: @user1551817 Phathomjs is the weapon of choice. There are python binding to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to use the [`pyautogui` module](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui), which allows you to programmatically control the mouse and the keyboard?

An example of an automatic form filler on a webpage is available in [chapter 18](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/) of the *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* book.

Comment: Links can be helpful, but it's much better to include the relevant part of the link in your answer, in case the links stop working.