# How to click on a button using Golang for Web Scraping

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a site using **Golang** and in order to get more content I need to click on a `<button>` and wait some seconds. (Notice: There is no Pagination in the site)

I found some cool packages to do web scraping like:

- **surf** (gopkg.in/headzoo/surf.v1)
- **goquery** (github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery)

But I can't find how to click on a button.

Is there a **package** that can do that? Or do I need to use **ChromeDriver/Headless Chrome/etc.**?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

As found in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823658/4784357

Open the `Network tab` in the web browser developer tools and **check what is happening when clicking the button** to continue using a package like goquery, surf, etc.

In other cases, a web browser needs to be automated to do such task.

Comment: This by no means address the question.